# Pass multiple "random" variables by controller to jsp

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp

I've tried to pass multiple "Random" variable by the Controller to my JSP page. I'm aware of how to pass a single variable or more variable called with a different name, but I've posted the below code like that I'm not able to do so.

Controller.class

```
model.addAttribute("Size", list.size());
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
            model.addAttribute("ListString"+i, list.get(i));
        }

        return "FinalList";
```

FinalList.jsp

```
   <c:forEach var = "i" begin = "0" end = "${Size}">

           ${ListString+i} <br><p>

      </c:forEach>
```

What I'm trying to do at ${ListString+i} is to rename that as ${ListString0}, ${ListString1} etc... but is not working.

Comment: Please explain what is not working as expected (error message, ...)

Comment: Can you update your question and put the actual output and expected output portion so we can understand better and able to solve your problem.

Comment: I update the question (sorry I'm new here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can use the List instead of `"+i"`

**Controller**

```
model.addAttribute("Lst", list);
return "FinalList";
```

**JSP**

```
<c:forEach var="window" items="${Lst}" varStatus="loopCounter" >
    <c:out value="count: ${loopCounter.count}"/>
    <c:out value="${window}"/>
</c:forEach>
```